# How do I pass ArrayList<Object> from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, serialization, parcelable

I want to pass ArrayList of an Object from one Activity to Activity.

Here is the sample Code:

```
{
    ArrayList<object> list=new ArrayList<>();

    Object value[]=new Object[m.size()];
    int n=0;

    value[]=new Object[n];
    value[n]=data.getName("name");
    value[n]=data.getLocation("location");

    list.add(value[n]);
    n++; //Since there are "n" number of object 
    
    }
    
    //here the value a which is ArrayList Object
    // which I want to pass it from here to another activity.
```

So now how will I pass the object from here to another activity.
**However**, I am able to get the value using **Gson**.
By converting the value to **json** and pass it as String to **SharedPreference**
and retrieving from another activity then convert back from **Json** using the **Type** to back it's Original form.

I want to know whether is it possible to pass the value using **Parceable**. Because I am getting null value when I used it.

here is the code which I tried to make my Object variable Parceable:

```
public class ProductList implements Parcelable {

private String NAME;
private String LOCATION;

public ProductList() {
}

protected ProductList(Parcel in) {
    LOCATION= in.readString();
    NAME= in.readString();
   
}

public static final Creator<ProductList> CREATOR = new Creator<ProductList>() {
    @Override
    public ProductList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ProductList(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProductList[size];
    }
};

public String getNAME() {
    return NAME;
}
public void setNAME(String NAME) {
    this.NAME= NAME;
}
public String getLOCATION() {
    return LOCATION;
}
public void setITEM_IMAGE(String LOCATION) {
    this.LOCATION= LOCATION;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(NAME);
    dest.writeString(LOCATION);
}
}
```

Comment: you can pass by serializing the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use activity result

link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

code example

Code in activity principal

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

In other activity

You can use the json format to pass the data

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObj);

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",json);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity
```

if you don't want to use activity result, you can use singleton class

```
class MyClass{ 
    companion object {
        val staticField = "This is an example of static field Object Decleration"
        fun getStaticFunction(): String {
            return "This is example of static function for Object Decleration"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way I guess I have to add all the "key" for the variable which I am going to pass. Is it not possible to pass it as Perceable??

Comment: maybe, but i prefer  to pass the json. i updated the code to pass the data, also you can use singleton in android to get information

Comment: Thank you, I tried using it its the same but much better, the way you have guided.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/3056090) for understanding.

**Activity one:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            ArrayList<object> list=new ArrayList<>();
            intent.putExtra("LIST", list);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity Two:**

```
ArrayList<object> list = (ArrayList<object>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");
```

Also implement Serializable in your custom class.

```
public class ProductList implements Parcelable, Serializable
```

Comment: There is one thing which I don't get it, in my case I have two App, one for **Receiver** and the other one for **Updater**. The **Receiver** pulls the data updated by the **updater**, there this when the **updater** makes some changes in the server the **Receiver** app it get Crash returning exception * Attempt to invoke null value reference* on the **Arraylist<Product>** which I have passed it RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: I have found the solution for the one which I have commented. Thanks Bro!!!

Comment: @AthosTokbi Mark the answer as accepted if you felt this helped you.

Comment: Your resolution it helps but didn't resolve my solution when I tried I get null value reference. However, it helps me to go in deep about it. I have tried the other way around with shared preferences.